# How does [v.abs, -v] work?

Tags: ruby

I know that this code will return a number whose absolute value is the smallest:

```
arr.min_by { |v| [v.abs, -v] }
```

How does this part `[v.abs, -v]` work? Can somebody provide an interpretation of this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way comparison of arrays works is that the values are compared one by one. Aka the first from the first array with first from the second then second with second and so on. In other words this compares first by absolute values. If they are the same, it compares by negated values.

```
[1, 2].min_by { |v| [v.abs, -v] }  # => 1
[1, -1].min_by { |v| [v.abs, -v] } # => 1
```

In other words, instead of having the natural order of

> ..., -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, ...

You have

> 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, ...

Comment: Readers may wish to look at the doc for [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (third paragraph).

Comment: ✅, you are [whistling in the wind](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/whistle-in-the-wind.1884288/).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, your tick signs are getting awesomer.

Answer (score 0):

`v.abs` returns the absolute value of the number:

```
-10.abs
=> 10
```

And `-v` will just give you the number with inverted sign:

```
v = 10
-v
=> -10
v = -10
-v
=> 10
```

`min_by` will compare first the absolute and then the negated values. So it gives you the smaller number in the array don't matter the sign:

```
[-1, 2, -3].min_by { |v| [v.abs, -v] }
=> -1
[1,2,-3].min_by { |v| [v.abs, -v] }
=> 1
```

Comment: This is misleading. If you just wanted "the smaller number in the array don't matter the sign" you could just use abs. What happens if the absolute value is the same is essential.